# Having issue T-SQL stored procedure adding qty's with an If Else condition with two tables, Fails @@roucount = 0

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Here's what I am trying to accomplish. This stored procedure needs to look in a table B and determine if the row exists.

If not, then the row is added from the data row in table A and also add the qty column from table A and updates table B qty column with the sum in the new row in table B.

If the row exists, simply add the qty column from table A to qty column in table B. No row needs to be inserted as it already exists.

Here's what I have so far. This does insert the new row in table B if it does not exist yet, but it fails to add table A to b if the does exist.

```
PROCEDURE [dbo].[xxxxxxxx]
    @VendorAccountID int,
    @pocomment text,
    @sqlident int output
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @TotalOnHand INT;  --newly declared, not assigned. NULL   
    DECLARE @POLineItemQty int

    INSERT INTO [PurchaseOrder_tbl] ([POVendorID], [pocomment])
    VALUES (@VendorAccountID, @pocomment)

    SET @sqlident = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

    UPDATE [PurchaseOrderTmp_tbl]
    SET POID = @sqlident

    UPDATE [PurchaseOrder_tbl]
    SET POTicketNumber = [PartOrderTicketID]
    FROM PurchaseOrderTmp_tbl
    WHERE PurchaseOrder_tbl.POID = @sqlident

    INSERT INTO PurchaseOrderItems_tbl(POID, VendorAccountID, POTicketID, POInvItemID, POLineItemQty, PartManufPartNum, PartOrderDesc, PartOrderManufacture, PartOrderModel, POType, PODescription, POStatusID, PartRequestedBy, POGLCode)
        SELECT
            POID, VendorAccountID, PartOrderTicketID, PartInvID, 
            POItemQty, PartManufPartNum, PartOrderDesc, PartOrderManufacture,
            PartOrderModel, POType, PODescription, POStatusID, 
            PartRequestedBy, POGLCode
        FROM
            PurchaseOrderTmp_tbl

    IF @@Rowcount = 0
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO InventoryMaster_tbl (InvManufacture, InvModel, InvManPartNumber, InvDescription)
            SELECT 
                PartOrderManufacture, PartOrderModel, PartManufPartNum, PartOrderDesc
            FROM
                PurchaseOrderTmp_tbl

        SELECT @TotalOnHand = (SELECT SUM(TotalOnHand)
                               FROM (Values (InvTotalQtyOnOrder), (@POLineItemQty)) AS TSum(TotalOnHand))
        FROM InventoryMaster_tbl

        UPDATE [InventoryMaster_tbl]
        SET InvTotalQtyOnOrder = InvTotalQtyOnOrder + POLineItemQty 
        FROM InventoryMaster_tbl
        INNER JOIN PurchaseOrderItems_tbl PartManufPartNum On PartManufPartNum = InvManPartNumber
        WHERE InvManPartNumber = PartManufPartNum
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT @TotalOnHand = (SELECT SUM(TotalOnHand)
                               FROM (Values (InvTotalQtyOnOrder), (@POLineItemQty)) as TSum(TotalOnHand))
        FROM InventoryMaster_tbl

        UPDATE [InventoryMaster_tbl]
        SET InvTotalQtyOnOrder = InvTotalQtyOnOrder + POLineItemQty 
        FROM InventoryMaster_tbl
        INNER JOIN PurchaseOrderItems_tbl PartManufPartNum On PartManufPartNum = InvManPartNumber
        WHERE InvManPartNumber = PartManufPartNum
    END

    DELETE PurchaseOrderTmp_tbl
END
```

Thanks in advance.

Version two. This does add the qty field IF the row exist but fails if row count = 0. Does not add row there for does not have anything to add.

```
PROCEDURE [dbo].[XXXXXXXX]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @VendorAccountID int,
    @pocomment text,
    @sqlident int output

AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @TotalOnHand INT;  --newly declared, not assigned. NULL   
    DECLARE @POLineItemQty int

INSERT INTO [PurchaseOrder_tbl] 
    ([POVendorID],[pocomment])
Values (@VendorAccountID,@pocomment)
SET @sqlident = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

UPDATE [PurchaseOrderTmp_tbl]

SET POID = @sqlident

UPDATE [PurchaseOrder_tbl]
Set POTicketNumber = [PartOrderTicketID]
From PurchaseOrderTmp_tbl
Where PurchaseOrder_tbl.POID = @sqlident

INSERT INTO PurchaseOrderItems_tbl
     (POID,VendorAccountID,POTicketID,POInvItemID,POLineItemQty,PartManufPartNum,PartOrderDesc,PartOrderManufacture,PartOrderModel,POType,PODescription,POStatusID,PartRequestedBy,POGLCode)
Select POID, VendorAccountID, PartOrderTicketID, PartInvID, POItemQty,PartManufPartNum,PartOrderDesc,PartOrderManufacture,PartOrderModel,POType,PODescription,POStatusID,PartRequestedBy,POGLCode
From PurchaseOrderTmp_tbl

SELECT  @TotalOnHand = (Select Sum(TotalOnHand)
    FROM (Values (InvTotalQtyOnOrder), (@POLineItemQty)) as TSum(TotalOnHand))
FROM InventoryMaster_tbl

UPDATE [InventoryMaster_tbl]
SET InvTotalQtyOnOrder = InvTotalQtyOnOrder + POLineItemQty 
FROM InventoryMaster_tbl
INNER JOIN PurchaseOrderItems_tbl PartManufPartNum On PartManufPartNum = InvManPartNumber
WHERE InvManPartNumber = PartManufPartNum
END
BEGIN


IF @@Rowcount = 0
BEGIN
INSERT INTO InventoryMaster_tbl
    (InvManufacture, InvModel, InvManPartNumber, InvDescription)
    SELECT PartOrderManufacture, PartOrderModel, PartManufPartNum, PartOrderDesc
    From PurchaseOrderTmp_tbl

SELECT  @TotalOnHand = (Select Sum(TotalOnHand)
    FROM (Values (InvTotalQtyOnOrder), (@POLineItemQty)) as TSum(TotalOnHand))
FROM InventoryMaster_tbl

UPDATE [InventoryMaster_tbl]
SET InvTotalQtyOnOrder = InvTotalQtyOnOrder + POLineItemQty 
FROM InventoryMaster_tbl
INNER JOIN PurchaseOrderItems_tbl PartManufPartNum On PartManufPartNum = InvManPartNumber
WHERE InvManPartNumber = PartManufPartNum

END

Delete PurchaseOrderTmp_tbl
END
```

Comment: Ok here's another version:

Comment: Ok here's another version: This version does add the qty's correctly before the @@rowcount. If the row exist just add the qty's. If the row does not exist it fails to insert new row and qty. Problem with the if statement?

Comment: I'm not clear on what the problem is.  You aren't actually asking a question!

Comment: I have no response for that. But thanks.

Comment: I didn't mean to offend.  I just mean, I don't know from what you've posted what aspect you're having trouble with. Is the procedure malfunctioning? Is there a feature you don't know how to add? Are you just asking whether you've made any obvious mistakes?

Comment: NP My bad. Read a 1000's of SO post over the years and that was kind of like those half I read. I am having issue with the if statement. Everything works fine until @@rowcount = 0. If the row does not exist insert into and than add. I'm talking example/try two from above. Make sense? And thanks again.

Comment: I understand.  Let's see if I can come up with anything.  Well, first, is the problem with the code inside the `IF` clause not being right, or with the `IF` clause itself not behaving like you expect?  Is it not executing the code inside when you think it should?

Comment: Yes. 1st step after if, row does not exist (which it does not), Insert into InventoryMaster. then add the totals as TSUm(totalonhand), As you can see the Tsum code is identical to the first part  (which does work). Since the row is not added everything else fails. I do not believe the IF @@rowcount is being hit at all. I wish you could step through SQL like VS but I never figured that out. Either SQL say ok or invalid syntax near.. Which is annoying. Thanks!

Comment: You have an extra `END BEGIN`  right before the `IF`.  Try taking that out and see if that changes the behavior. I'm thinking that the `END` might be signaling the parser that the stored procedure ends at that point (because the `BEGIN` it ties to is at the start of the proc.)  That could explain why the `IF` never seems to be hit!

Comment: You know I saw that after my last post and had already removed them.  Still never sees the IF. SP execute with no errors directly on the server so it's hard to trouble shoot.

Comment: You're certain that the update of `InventoryMaster_tbl` right above it results in 0 rows being updated?  (By the way, you don't need the `WHERE` clause if you've got the same condition in the `JOIN xxx ON ...` clause. Shouldn't do any harm, it's just redundant.)

Comment: You've probably also noticed that you aren't doing anything with `@TotalOnHand`.  You're calculating it but not using it. I mention this in case it was supposed to play a role in the logic.

Comment: Well I switch the two processes around. So my code that was below the IF  works fine when it is executed first. So both half's of my code works just never recognizes the IF. I even added another IF @@ROWCOUTN = 1. Still nothing. The last command DELETE does execute and deletes the row. Baffled..

Comment: Well I appreciate your help. there isn't any way to give you credit. I manage to get to work with a total re-write.